# Flutter image_picker is not working on macos.Can anyone suggest me which plugin are supported

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-macos-2.0.0-stable

I am currently in a crisis of cross platform i have an existing app for android and ios now. I wanted that in web and macOS now i am using image_picker in package now the problem is that image picker is not working for the macOS i have tried other packages to for the purpose so can you guys suggest me a package for the same or some way to access and get photos in macOS

Answer (score 1):

Image_picker is only available for iOS, Android and web. For desktop, you can use the [file_selector](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/tree/master/plugins/file_selector) plugin.

[image]

[image]